# Insert zeros in a list on Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to insert zeros after each element of a given list in prolog, could you help me please, I can't find the right way to make it work. This is my code:

```
insert_zero([A|T]),([A|B]):- 
   insert_zero([Rest|R1]), append(0,R1,B).
```

The answer should give me this

```
?- insert_zero([a,2,c,3], R). 
R = [a,0,2,0,c,0,3,0].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be implemented with a simple predicate:

```
insert_zero([],[]).
insert_zero([H|T],[H,0|T1]):-
    insert_zero(T,T1).

?- insert_zero([a,2,c,3], R).
R = [a, 0, 2, 0, c, 0, 3, 0].
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain me your solution, please. I'm a begginer.

Comment: When the list is empty (first argument), we get an empty list as result (second argument). This is the base case of the recursion (first clause). In the general case, when we have a list with first element H, we add this element to the list containing the result followed by a 0, then we call recursively the predicate on the remaining part of the list.